# How to prove that this function is negative?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Given two positive numbers $a$ and $\epsilon$. Define $g_{a,\epsilon}(x)$ for all positive $x$ as:

$$g_{a,\epsilon}(x)=(x+\epsilon)(e^{\frac{a}{x+\epsilon}}-1)-x(e^{\frac{a}{x}}-1).$$

I would like to show that $g_{a,\epsilon}(x)\leqslant0$ for all $x>0$, and $a,\epsilon>0$.

I calculate the derivative with respect to $x$ and I found:

$$g_{a,\epsilon}'(x)=e^{\frac{a}{x+\epsilon}}\left(1-\frac{a}{x+\epsilon}\right)+e^{\frac{a}{x}}\left(\frac{a}{x}-1\right).$$

Answer (score 4):

Much more effective is to take derivatives *with respect to $a$*:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial a} g_{a,\epsilon}(x) = e^{a/(x+\epsilon)} - e^{a/x} < 0
$$
for all $x,a,\epsilon>0$. So for any given $x,\epsilon>0$, the function $g_{a,\epsilon}(x)$ is a decreasing function of $a$ for $a>0$, which means
$$
g_{a,\epsilon}(x) \le g_{0,\epsilon}(x) = 0.
$$

Comment: Nice. Is there another way when $a$ is a positive integer (not real)?

Answer (score 1):

$g_{a,\epsilon}(x)=f(x+\epsilon)-f(x)$ with $f(x)=x(e^\frac{a}{x}-1)\,$, so $g_{a,\epsilon}(x) \le 0$ iff $ f(x)$ is decreasing on $\mathbb{R}^+$.

For $f$ to be decreasing, its derivative must be non-positive $f'(x)=e^\frac{a}{x}\big(1-\frac{a}{x}\big)-1\le 0$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}^+\iff h(y)=e^y(1-y) \le 1$ for $y \in \mathbb{R}^+$, which readily follows because $h'(y)= -y \,e^y \le 0$ thus $h(y) \le h(0)=1\,$. So in the end $h \le 1 \implies f' \le 0 \implies f$ decreasing $\implies g_{a,\epsilon} \le 0\,$.